# Stopping Floodfill algorithm

Tags: python, flood-fill

I'm stuck with my flood fill algo : it stops at a moment it "normally" shouldn't...

Here's the situation : I have a matrix 512*512 pixels and the values are either 50 or 100-ish. The values of 50 are forming a square that I want to change in a square with values of 255 (using the floodfill algo).

```
def FF(matrix,x,y,h):     #h is chosen <=50

    stack=[]
    matrix[x,y]=255

    stack.append((x,y))

    while stack!=[]:

        (x,y)=stack[0]

        stack.pop()


        if matrix[x-1,y] <= h:          #Pixel North
            matrix[x-1,y]=255
            stack.append((x-1,y))

        if matrix[x,y+1] <= h:          #Pixel East
           matrix[x,y+1]=255
           stack.append((x,y+1))

        if matrix[x+1,y] <= h:          #Pixel South
           matrix[x+1,y]=255
           stack.append((x+1,y))

        if matrix[x,y-1] <= h:          #Pixel West
           matrix[x,y-1]=255
           stack.append((x,y-1))

        if matrix[x-1,y+1] <= h:        #Pixel North East
           matrix[x-1,y+1]=255
           stack.append((x-1,y+1))

        if matrix[x+1,y+1] <= h:        #Pixel South East
           matrix[x+1,y+1]=255
           stack.append((x+1,y+1))

        if matrix[x+1,y-1] <= h:        #Pixel South West
           matrix[x+1,y-1]=255
           stack.append((x+1,y-1))

        if matrix[x-1,y-1] <= h:        #Pixel North West
           matrix[x-1,y-1]=255
           stack.append((x-1,y-1))

    else:
       print ('... finished')
       return
```

I don't know why but the code is working for 10 times but not more.

Thank you, Q.

Comment: Your `matrix[x-1,y] <= h:` does **not** check bounds. It checks the value of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is situated here:

```
    (x,y)=stack[0] # get the first element of the list
    stack.pop() # remove the *last* element
```

Since you obtain the first element, but remove the last one, it is possible (like and perhaps always the case), that *not* all elements will be evaluated that are pushed on the stack.

Nevertheless you make it **way too complex**. Simply write:

```
def FF(matrix,x,y,h):     #h is chosen <=50
    stack=[(x,y)]
    m,n = matrix.shape
    while stack:
        x,y = stack.pop()
        if 0 <= x < m and 0 <= y < n and matrix[x,y] <= h: # check bounds and height
            matrix[x,y] = 255 # set the value
            stack.append((x-1,y-1)) # add all directions to the stack, we check later
            stack.append((x,y-1))
            stack.append((x+1,y-1))
            stack.append((x-1,y))
            stack.append((x+1,y))
            stack.append((x-1,y+1))
            stack.append((x,y+1))
            stack.append((x+1,y+1))
```

Comment: After testing your code, it works perfectly and it is indeed much more simpler. Thanks you !

Comment: @QuentinL: I found the problem with your code and rewrote the answer.